# How to check whether a matrix is a framed matrix?

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix

Question:

Framed matrix example:

[image: Framed matrix example:]

The elements marked with the letter C indicate an internal matrix.

The elements marked with the letter B constitute a peripheral frame for the matrix whose members are marked with the letter C,
and the elements marked with the letter A constitute a peripheral frame for the matrix whose elements are marked with the letters B
and C.

A matrix will be called a "framed matrix" if all its elements that are marked with the same letter (A, B, C, and further) contain identical values. A generic normal framed matrix can be of any size.

Example for a framed matrix with numeric values:

[image: Example for a framed matrix with numeric values:]

I need to write a java function that receives a matrix as an argument, returns true if the matrix is framed
and false if not.

thanks for your help

I wrote a function that returns true if the outer layer contains identical values (the first and last rows, and the first and last columns), I need to check the inner layers as well.

that's my partial solution:

```
      public static boolean isFrameMatrix(int matrix[][])
  {
      int A = matrix[0][0];
      int rows = matrix.length;
      int cols = matrix[0].length;
      
    
      int i=0 ,j = 0;
      
      //Check the first and last rows
      for(j=0; j<cols; j++)
      {
          if(A != matrix[0][j] || A != matrix[rows-1][j]) return false;
      }
      
      //Check the first and last columns
      for(i = 0; i<rows; i++)
      {
          if(matrix[i][0] != A || matrix[i][cols-1] != A) return false;
      }
      
      return true;

  }
```

Comment: You should post your partial solution. The full solution would be a generalisation of it. You need a function that has an additional int parameter that show, whether yyou check teh first, second,... layer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To better understand this site and how to use it, I recommend the following resources, and pages they link to: [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), and [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Note that Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. It is expected questions of this type include code showing an attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: In addition, if this is homework, you should read [Open Letter regarding Homework](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems).

Comment: You asked a question before that got answers. But there is no feedback from you to either answers.

Comment: @Géza adding my partial solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where in your current code you use index `0` or `rows-1` (or `cols-1`), use an expression that takes into account at which frame you are looking. The number of frames is determined by the minimum of the width and height of the matrix, and half of that (rounded upwards). For instance, a 5x7 matrix has (5+1)/2 frames, i.e. 3

Here is how you can achieve that:

```
    public boolean isFrameMatrix(int[][] matrix) {
        int height = matrix.length;
        int width = matrix[0].length;

        for (int frame = (Math.min(width, height) + 1) / 2; frame >= 0; frame--) {
            int value = matrix[frame][frame];
            for (int col = frame + 1; col < width - frame; col++) {
                if (matrix[frame][col] != value || 
                        matrix[height - 1 - frame][col] != value) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            for (int row = frame + 1; row < height - frame; row++) {
                if (matrix[row][frame] != value || 
                        matrix[row][width - 1 - frame] != value) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the responses above is indeed a working solution.

In addition, I managed to reach another solution, with the use of recursion.

```
public static boolean isFramed(int[][] matrix, int rows, int cols) {
      
      // If we reached a situation where the number of columns is less than 2
      // or the number of rows is less than 2 without encountering FALSE along the way,
      // then all the layers of the matrix are framed.
      if(rows < 2 || cols < 2) return true;
      
      // 'A' can be considered as a pivot, first&last rows, first&last columns must be equal to to 'A'
      int A = matrix[0][0];
      
      //Check the first and last rows
      for(int j=0; j<cols; j++)
      {
          if(A != matrix[0][j] || A != matrix[rows-1][j]) return false;
      }
      
      //Check the first and last columns
      for(int i = 0; i<rows; i++)
      {
          if(matrix[i][0] != A || matrix[i][cols-1] != A) return false;
      }
      
      // Move to inner layers, create a new matrix without the current border we just checked.
      int [][]mat = new int[rows-2][cols-2];
      
      int newRows = 0; //
      for(int i = 1; i < matrix.length - 1; i++)
      {
          int newCols = 0;
          for(int j = 1; j < matrix[0].length - 1; j++)
          {

              mat[newRows][newCols++] = matrix[i][j];
              
          }
          newRows++;
      }
      printMatrix(mat);
      
      //Recursive call to the function
      return isFramed(mat, rows-2, cols-2);
    
    }
```

Comment: Give a more abstract concept like: 

"Given this scenario <explain> how could I determine that  the matrix is a framed matrix, here is a sample of code that I use to generate and test that theory"

Answer (score 0):

I will submit an answer in Ruby. It can be viewed as pseudo-code and should be easily translated to Javascript.

```
def check_it(arr)
  n = arr.size
  last_idx = n - 1
  diag = (0..last_idx).map { |i| arr[i][i] }
  # Confirm diagonal is symmetric
  return false if diag[0, n/2] != diag[n/2..-1].reverse
  # test all elements
  (0..last_idx).all? do |i|
    (0..last_idx).all? do |j|
      k = diag_idx(last_idx, i,j)
      arr[i][j] == arr[k][k]
    end
  end
end
```

```
def diag_idx(last_idx,i,j)
  # if i,j is a row, k = i, else k = j
  k = is_row?(last_idx,i,j) ? i : j
  adj_idx(last_idx, k)
end
```

```
def is_row?(last_idx,i,j)
  # move i to first half of rows if is last half
  i = last_idx - i if i > last_idx/2 
  j >= i && j <= last_idx - i
end
```

```
def adj_idx(last_idx,k)
  [k, last_idx - k].min
end
```

---

```
arr = [[8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8, 8],
       [8, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 8],
       [8, 66, 51, 51, 51, 51, 66, 8],  
       [8, 66, 51,  4,  4, 51, 66, 8],
       [8, 66, 51,  4,  4, 51, 66, 8],
       [8, 66, 51, 51, 51, 51, 66, 8],
       [8, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 8],
       [8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8, 8]]
```

```
check_it(arr) #=> true
```

```
arr[5,1] = 67 # was 66
check_it(arr) #=> false
```

```
arr[5,1] = 66
arr[1,6] = 67 # was 66
check_it(arr) #=> false
```

```
arr[1,6] = 66
arr[4][4] = 5 # was 4
check_it(arr) #=> false
```

---

The method `is_row?` computes the following for each element in the array.

```
last_idx = arr.size-1
(0..last_idx).each do |i|
  (0..last_idx).map do |j|
    print "#{is_row?(last_idx,i,j) ? "True   " : "False  "}" }
  end
  puts
end
```

```
True   True   True   True   True   True   True   True   
False  True   True   True   True   True   True   False  
False  False  True   True   True   True   False  False  
False  False  False  True   True   False  False  False  
False  False  False  True   True   False  False  False  
False  False  True   True   True   True   False  False  
False  True   True   True   True   True   True   False  
True   True   True   True   True   True   True   True
```

---

The method `adj_idx` computes the following for each element in the array.

```
last_idx = arr.size - 1
(0..last_idx).each do |i|
  (0..last_idx).each do |j|
    print "%7d" % diag_idx(last_idx,i,j)
  end  
  puts
end
```

```
    0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
    0      1      1      1      1      1      1      0
    0      1      2      2      2      2      1      0
    0      1      2      3      3      2      1      0
    0      1      2      3      3      2      1      0
    0      1      2      2      2      2      1      0
    0      1      1      1      1      1      1      0
    0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
```

**-----------------------------------------------------------------------**

A second way is less efficient but requires less code and is easy to understand, in part because it employs no indices. The ideas is to slice off the first row, rotate the array 90 degrees anticlockwise, and repeat three more times.

The four slices are then examined to confirm that they all contain the same unique element. If more than one unique element is found `false` is returned; else the processes is repeated with the array whose first and last rows and columns have been removed. If a 2x2 array is reached `true` is returned if the array contains one unique element; else false is returned.

This approach uses a method to rotate its argument, an `n x m` array, 90 degrees anticlockwise (a.k.a., counterclockwise).

```
def rotate_90_anti(arr)
  arr.map { |row| row.reverse }.transpose
end
```

For example, if

```
a =   [[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]]
```

then

```
rotate_90_anti(a)
  #=> [[3, 6, 9],
  #    [2, 5, 8],
  #    [1, 4, 7]]
```

The main method follows.

```
 def check_it(arr)
   # Make a deep copy of arr
   ar = arr.dup.map { |row| row.dup }
   loop do # repeat forever
     return (ar.flatten.uniq.size == 1) if ar.size == 2
     a = []
     4.times do |i|
       # Slice first row and add elements to a
       a.concat(ar.shift)
       # Rotate the resulting ar 
       ar = rotate_90_anti(ar) if i < 3
     end
     # Return false if elements in outer frame are not all equal
     # a.uniq removes duplicate elements
     return false if a.uniq.size > 1
   end
 end
```

---

The calculations are illustrated below.

```
arr1 = 
   [[66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66],
    [66, 51, 51, 51, 51, 66],  
    [66, 51, 34, 34, 51, 66],
    [66, 51, 34, 34, 51, 66],
    [66, 51, 51, 51, 51, 66],
    [66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66]]
```

```
check_it arr1
  #=> true
ar.size == 2 #=> false

a = []
i = 0
a = [66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66]
ar after slice = 
   [[66, 51, 51, 51, 51, 66],
    [66, 51, 34, 34, 51, 66],
    [66, 51, 34, 34, 51, 66],
    [66, 51, 51, 51, 51, 66],
    [66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66]]
ar after rotating = 
   [[66, 66, 66, 66, 66],
    [51, 51, 51, 51, 66],
    [51, 34, 34, 51, 66],
    [51, 34, 34, 51, 66],
    [51, 51, 51, 51, 66],
    [66, 66, 66, 66, 66]]
```

```
i = 1
a = [66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66]
ar after slice = 
   [[51, 51, 51, 51, 66],
    [51, 34, 34, 51, 66],
    [51, 34, 34, 51, 66],
    [51, 51, 51, 51, 66],
    [66, 66, 66, 66, 66]]
ar after rotating = 
   [[66, 66, 66, 66, 66],
    [51, 51, 51, 51, 66],
    [51, 34, 34, 51, 66],
    [51, 34, 34, 51, 66],
    [51, 51, 51, 51, 66]]
```

```
i = 2    
a = [66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66]
ar after slice = 
   [[51, 51, 51, 51, 66],
    [51, 34, 34, 51, 66],
    [51, 34, 34, 51, 66],
    [51, 51, 51, 51, 66]]
ar after rotating = 
   [[66, 66, 66, 66],
    [51, 51, 51, 51],
    [51, 34, 34, 51],
    [51, 34, 34, 51],
    [51, 51, 51, 51]]
```

```
i = 3
a = [66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66,
     66, 66, 66, 66]
ar after slice = 
   [[51, 51, 51, 51],
    [51, 34, 34, 51],
    [51, 34, 34, 51],
    [51, 51, 51, 51]]
```

```
a.uniq = [66]
a.uniq.size = 1
a.uniq.size > 1 #=> false
```

```
ar.size == 2 #=> false
a = []
i = 0
a = [51, 51, 51, 51]
ar after slice = 
   [[51, 34, 34, 51],
    [51, 34, 34, 51],
    [51, 51, 51, 51]]
ar after rotating = 
   [[51, 51, 51],
    [34, 34, 51],
    [34, 34, 51],
    [51, 51, 51]]
```

```
i = 1    
a = [51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51]
ar after slice = 
   [[34, 34, 51],
    [34, 34, 51],
    [51, 51, 51]]
ar after rotating = 
   [[51, 51, 51],
    [34, 34, 51],
    [34, 34, 51]]
```

```
i = 2
a = [51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51]
ar after slice = 
   [[34, 34, 51],
    [34, 34, 51]]
ar after rotating = 
   [[51, 51],
    [34, 34],
    [34, 34]]
```

```
i = 3
a = [51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51]
ar after slice = 
   [[34, 34],
    [34, 34]]
ar after rotating = 
   [[34, 34],
    [34, 34]]
```

```
a.uniq = [51]
a.uniq.size = 1
a.uniq.size > 1 #=> false
```

```
ar.size == 2              #=> true
ar.flatten                #=> [34, 34, 34, 34]
ar.flatten.uniq           #=> [34]
ar.flatten.uniq.size == 1 #=> true
```

Answer (score -4):

If I understand you correctly, you need to check all border elements lets say non-zero neighbors, then the matrix is framed. Here`s my old homework solution:

```
public static boolean isFramed(int[][] matrix) {
    int rows = matrix.length;
    int cols = matrix[0].length;

    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        if (matrix[0][j] == 0 || matrix[rows - 1][j] == 0)
            return false;
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        if (matrix[i][0] == 0 || matrix[i][cols - 1] == 0)
            return false;
    }
    
    return true;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] matrix = {
        {1, 1, 1, 1},
        {1, 0, 0, 1},
        {1, 0, 0, 1},
        {1, 1, 1, 1}
    };

    boolean isFramedMatrix = isFramed(matrix);
    System.out.println("Is the matrix framed? " + isFramedMatrix);
}
```

You can make the adjustment to fit your goal.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the ultimate goal of the function is to check all the layers in the matrix.
for example:

    int [][]matrix = new int[][] {{8, 8, 8, 8},
           {8, 7, 7, 8},
           {8, 6, 7, 8},
           {8, 8, 8, 8}};

For this matrix, both my matrix and your matrix will return true, but it should return false because the '6' element in matrix[2][1] is wrong..
This is the part I'm having trouble with.

Comment: @Nuevo, if you have such comments, then why did you mark the answer as accepted?

Comment: I accepted his answer because the answer does help, but does not solve the problem completely.

Comment: This clearly is  incorrect. `if (matrix[0][j] == 0 ...` alone tells us that. The OP's problem is very clear so why do not make the "adjustment" you refer to in your last sentence. One of the downvotes is mine.